# MySQL SELECT with WHERE clause not including results with amount '0'

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I am trying to create a select stored procedure to return the count distinct instances of a value. However if no distinct instances exist it should return 0. The following query almost does everything I need

```
SELECT br.barangay,COUNT(DISTINCT cr.cr_patient_no) as `amount`
FROM barangay as br LEFT JOIN case_report_main as cr  on cr.cr_barangay = br.barangay
GROUP BY br.barangay 
ORDER BY br.barangay  ASC
```

This code returns the column 'barangay' which contains names of locations and the 'count' column. However, I also need to be able to search through them using a WHERE clause.

```
WHERE cr.cr_date_onset BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2014-12-12'
```

I need a result that includes the 0 amount like the following:

```
'NAME1'|'1'
'NAME2'|'0'
'NAME3'|'4'
'NAME4'|'0'
```

But when I add the WHERE clause, it removes all results with the amount 0.

```
'NAME1'|'1'
'NAME3'|'4'
```

Can someone please provide a solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure that there are 0 values within that date range?

Comment: try using ISNULL(count(*), 0)

Comment: yes, I am sure that there are. The query result from the version without the where clause looks exactly it does in the example. 

I'll give ISNULL a look

Comment: go for ifnull. it will work

Comment: @IPerfect no it won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your WHERE clause:

```
cr.cr_date_onset IS NULL OR cr.cr_date_onset BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2014-12-12'
```

Comment: This and JW's answer both worked. Thanks for the input everyone.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add that condition on the `ON` clause, not on the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT  br.barangay,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cr.cr_patient_no) AS `amount`
FROM    barangay AS br
        LEFT JOIN case_report_main AS cr
            ON  cr.cr_barangay = br.barangay AND
                cr.cr_date_onset BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2014-12-12'
GROUP   BY br.barangay
ORDER   BY br.barangay ASC
```

Comment: +1 The condition can be in the WHERE too, but coupled with an OR IS NULL :)

Comment: @Jack yeah i didn't think of it. hehehe

Comment: This is nice too, though; the condition is exactly in the right spot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
    SELECT br.barangay,ifnull(COUNT(DISTINCT cr.cr_patient_no),0) as `amount`
    FROM barangay as br LEFT JOIN case_report_main as cr  on cr.cr_barangay = br.barangay 
    where cr.cr_date_onset between '2010-01-01' and '2014-12-12'
    GROUP BY br.barangay 
    ORDER BY br.barangay  ASC
```

Comment: the results were the same as before, thanks for the input though!